# How to `automate` the `stylus` nib for static web page?

Tags: jquery, css, stylus

I am using `stylus` to create my `css` file. in the `css3` vendor prefix and other advantage, i use the `nib` package.

I an not building my website using express or any other server. this is pure static. now i require to run the `nib` package whenever the `.styl` file changes.

At present i am doing by manual running this command:

`stylus -u nib screen.styl` - it works well. But i don't want to run this each and every time i change the `.styl` file.

Is there a automation to run this? or any other work-around to handle this?

sample css for above command :

```
@import 'nib'

#comments
    border-radius 4
    box-shadow 0 9 1px black

    p
        opacity 0.75

.seeen
    border-radius 4

#slogan
    hide-text()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `--watch` (or just `-w`) flag:

```
stylus -u nib -w screen.styl
```

Comment: Nope, Watch only works, if I am not use the `nib`. when i import the `nib` it throws error.

Comment: It should work. Try to install nib globally (`npm install nib -g`).

Comment: Here is the error : `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TCP\css>stylus -w screen.styl
  watching C:/Users/Mohamed.Arif/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/stylus/lib/fun
ctions/index.styl
Error: screen.styl:1:9
   1| @import 'nib'
--------------^
   2|
   3| #comments
   4|   border-radius 4

failed to locate @import file nib.styl
`

Comment: The error message means that you haven't installed nib globally. Run `npm install nib -g`.

Comment: I have installed already only in `globel` let me do again, and get back to you.

Comment: No luck:  `
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TCP\css>npm install nib -g
nib@1.1.0 C:\Users\Mohamed.Arif\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nib
└── stylus@0.49.3 (css-parse@1.7.0, mkdirp@0.3.5, sax@0.5.8, source-map@0.1.43,
debug@2.2.0, glob@3.2.11)

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TCP\css>stylus -w screen.styl
  watching C:/Users/Mohamed.Arif/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/stylus/lib/fun
ctions/index.styl
Error: screen.styl:1:9
   1| @import 'nib'
--------------^
   2|
   3| #comments
   4|   border-radius 4

failed to locate @import file nib.styl
`